# Seleccionar parte de un código HTML en python, con Web Scraping

Tags: python, json, web

Tengo un código que corresponde a una ciudad, y necesito construir una especie de "mapa del tiempo". Para ello uso la API de MeteoGalicia. El problema reside en que mi código de la localidad (código postal), no corresponde con el que utiliza dicha API para identificar las localidades.
Tengo acceso a un fichero json que contiene todas las localidades con el correspondiente código de la API, pero necesito asignarlo. EL fichero json lo he convertido a un HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
solicitud = requests.get('http://servizos.meteogalicia.es/apiv3/findPlaces?location='+'milocalidad'+'&API_KEY=' + ClaveMeteoSIX()).json()
# ClaveMeteoSIX() es simplemente la API Key que es necesaria para usar la API

# Lo convierto a HTML:
solicitudHTML = json2html.json2html.convert(json = solicitud)

# Y ahora lo parseo:
solicitudParseada = BeautifulSoup(solicitudHTML,'html.parser')
```

Vale, el formato resultante es una tabla del siguiente estilo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, he buscado la localidad de "OLEIROS", y me devuelve una tabla que contiene "oleiros" en alguno de los atributos, entonces me interesa seleccionar aquel atributo en el que el municipio sea "OLEIROS" y después, obtener el id. el código de una de las subtablas es el siguiente:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <td>48202</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <td>Oleiros</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>municipality</th>
        <td>OLEIROS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>province</th>
        <td>A Coru�a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>type</th>
        <td>locality</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Para encontrarlo tengo que usar (si es posible) el módulo bs4, es posible seleccionar un municipio con un valor concreto (en este caso, Oleiros) y después obtener el valor del id?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de resolverlo, una de ellas sería usar `find_all` para encontrar todas las etiquetas `<th>` con texto "municipality", por cada una de ellas buscamos si el subsiguiente `<td>` tiene el municipio a buscar, si lo tiene referenciamos el "abuelo" y obtenemos el texto del primer `<td>` (la ID):

```
solicitudHTML = """\ 

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <td>48202</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <td>Oleiros</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>municipality</th>
        <td>OLEIROS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>province</th>
        <td>A Coruña</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>type</th>
        <td>locality</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <td>49984</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <td>Oleiros</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>municipality</th>
        <td>RIBEIRA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>province</th>
        <td>A Coruña</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>type</th>
        <td>locality</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>"""
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



municipio = "Oleiros"


mun = municipio.lower()
id_ = None
solicitudParseada = BeautifulSoup(solicitudHTML,'html.parser')
for td in solicitudParseada.find_all("th", text="municipality"):
    if td.parent.find_next('td').text.lower() == mun:
        id_ = td.parent.parent.find_next("td").text
        break
print(id_)
```

> 48202